# dynamically determine the ticks in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way in d3.js to dynamically determine the x axis values?
I have an array of date values. Now I'd like apply some kind of filter which always returns a defined number of dates (let's say 4). (Similar to setting the ticks by .ticks(4))

In addition to this I always want the first and the last date to be displayed and the remaining (two in this case) dates should be filtered dynamically. At best these two values will lie exactly in between the start and end with equal time offset.

The input dates can be arbitrary date values, i.e., the first couple time values could be different month within the same year and the following values could be different years, such as:

```
["2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-08-01", "2015-09-01", "2015-10-01", "2015-11-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01"]
```

Comment: The only way to achieve exactly what you want is to set the ticks explicitly using `.tickValues()`. You can approximate though by calling `.nice()` on the scale and `.ticks(number + 2)`.

Comment: thanks! I thought so, I'm already using .tickValues and determine the tick values manually beforehand. I'll try the approach by using .nice().